# How much of additive is in the tank?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> A storage tank contains 7570.8 L of gasoline that initially has 45.3 kg of an additive dissolved in it. In preparation for winter weather, gasoline containing 0.24 kg of additive per ml is pumped into the tank at a rate of 151.4 L/min. The well-mixed solution is pumped out at a rate of 170.3 L/min. How much additive is in the tank 20 min after the pumping process begins (See Figure below)?

> Take $y(t)$ is the amount of chemical in the container at time $t$ and $V(t)$ is the total volume of liquid in the container at time $t$.

[image]

**My attempt**:

I assume that no amount is going out of the tank then I can get the following things

The amount of chemical in time $t$ min $=$ Initial amount + accumulated amount in time t
$$y_1=45.3+0.24\times 151.4\times t\ kg=45.3+36336t\ kg$$

The volume of solution in the tank after time $t$ min $=$ Initial volume + accumulated volume in time t
$$=7570.8+151.4\times t =7570.8+151.4t \ L$$

The concentration of chemical i.e. the amount of chemical per L of solution at time $t$ is
$$=\frac{45.3+36336t}{7570.8+151.4t }\ kg\L$$

Now, the solution is taken out of the tank,

The amount is taken out of the tank in time $t=$ draining rate $\times$ concentration

$$y_2=170.3\times \frac{45.3+36336t}{7570.8+151.4t}$$

therefore the amount of chemical $y(t)$ left in the tank at time $t=$ amount accumulated in time $t-$ amount taken out of the tank in time $t$

$$y(t)=y_1-y_2$$$$=45.3+36336t-170.3\times \frac{45.3+36336t}{7570.8+151.4t}$$
now, substituting $t=20$ second in above formula, the amount left in tank
$$y(t)=45.3+36336(20)-170.3\times \frac{45.3+36336(20)}{7570.8+151.4(20)}$$
$$=715087.74 \ kg$$
I am not sure if I am right. Please point out my mistake if any.

Is there another way to solve this problem differential equation with initial conditions?
please help me solve this.

thanks in advance.